# Best practice to create robots.txt file inside my asp.net mvc web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, robots.txt

I want to create a robots.txt for my asp.net mvc-5 web site, now I find this link which talks about achieving this task:-

http://rehansaeed.com/dynamically-generating-robots-txt-using-asp-net-mvc/

where in this link they are creating a separate Controller & Route rule to build the robots.txt ,,,so I am not sure why i can not just create the `robot.txt` file and add it to the root of my web site as follow:-:-

[image]

where if I navigate to the following URL `http://www.mywebsite.com/robots.txt` the text content will be shown ,without having to create separate controller for this?

so my question is if it is valid to add the robots.txt directly to my web site root without having to do so inside a controller and separate route rule , to keep things simpler ??

Comment: Yes, go ahead and add `robots.txt` manually. Those links are building dynamic site maps (not the robot file) so you wouldn't need to update the sitemap xml manually.

Comment: @jasen sorry seems I provide a wrong URL, I updated my question with the correct url I am talking about , where in that example they define a route rule as follow  [Route("robots.txt", Name = "GetRobotsText"), OutputCache(Duration = 86400)]

Comment: I can't remember that last time I said _"I wish my robots file were real-time dynamically generated"_. But I guess it's cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically generate the content, then that makes sense because it would give you that ability.  But otherwise, I use a robots.txt file in my applications with no problems.

Answer (score 6):

On my website, asp net core 3.1, I just used the below simple action:

```
    [Route("/robots.txt")]
    public ContentResult RobotsTxt()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("User-agent: *")
            .AppendLine("Disallow:")
            .Append("sitemap: ")
            .Append(this.Request.Scheme)
            .Append("://")
            .Append(this.Request.Host)
            .AppendLine("/sitemap.xml");

        return this.Content(sb.ToString(), "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

Comment: For a simple/static robots.txt I find it easier to return directly from endpoint routing, such as `endpoints.MapGet("/robots.txt", async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("User-Agent: *\nAllow: /"));`

Answer (score 1):

Placing a robots.txt file in the MVC application root as shown in your screenshot, the same place as Startup.cs, worked well for me.